# Can the POTUS put checks and balances on his own otherwise unilateral nuclear powers?

Tags: united-states, president

Could the POTUS implement some form of checks and balances with regards to his otherwise unilateral, unquestionable ability to use nukes? Without needing congress to pass a bill?

If so, would he HAVE to use an executive order? Or, could he just tell those lower then him in the chain of command to ignore him if some condition is not met, or if someone like the VP didn't agree with the choice? Or could he even bestow upon the VP or others the ability to veto his decision?

Comment: can god create a stone so heavy he can't lift it?

Comment: Related question: [May the US president launch a nuclear bomb without any oversight on any target?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9844/may-the-us-president-launch-a-nuclear-bomb-without-any-oversight-on-any-target) (tl;dr: There already is a check in place. The Secretary of Defense needs to approve the order)

Comment: ColinZwanziger, I was asking if the POTUS can order those below him to ignore his nuke request under certain circumstances, like "If I sound drunk I probably am; so don't nuke thing then, m'kay?". I was asking if they're allowed to listen to this kind of request, or if they have no choice but to proceed.